# Create a completion block that returns nothing but executes another function when completed?

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler, completion-block

I'm trying to create a completion block that can execute another function after its completed, in this case it's a tableview reload. I get the error :

> 'async' produces '()', not the expected contextual result type 'Bool'

This is the function:

```
  func appendAllData (completion: () -> Bool) {

    if self.movieDetailsData?.poster != nil {
      if let posterImage = self.movieDetailsData?.poster {
        self.posterArray.append(posterImage)
      }
    }
    if self.movieDetailsData?.overview != nil {
      if let overview = self.movieDetailsData?.overview {
        self.overviewArray.append(overview)
      }
    }

    if self.movieDetailsData?.releaseData != nil {
      if let releaseDate = self.movieDetailsData?.releaseData {
        self.releaseInfoArray.append(releaseDate)
      }
    }

    if self.movieDetailsData?.runtime != nil {
      if let runtime = self.movieDetailsData?.runtime {
        self.releaseInfoArray.append(String(describing: runtime))
      }
    }

    if self.movieDetailsData?.genre != nil {
      if let genre = self.movieDetailsData?.genre {
        if genre.isEmpty {
        } else {
          self.releaseInfoArray.append(genre[0].name)
        }
      }
    }

    if self.movieDetailsData?.budget != nil {
      if let budget = self.movieDetailsData?.budget {
        self.boxOfficeArray.append(budget)
      }
    }

    if self.movieDetailsData?.revenue != nil {
      if let revenue = self.movieDetailsData?.revenue {
        self.boxOfficeArray.append(revenue)
      }
    }

    if self.movieDetailsData?.homepage != nil {
      if let homepage = self.movieDetailsData?.homepage {
        self.homePageArray.append(homepage)
      }
    }

    if self.movieDetailsData?.images != nil {
      if let images = self.movieDetailsData?.images {

        let posters = images.backdropImages
        for poster in posters {

          self.imageArray.append(poster.filePath)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is how it's used:

```
 self.appendAllData(completion: { _ in

  DispatchQueue.main.async { //error here: 'async' produces '()', not the expected contextual result type 'Bool'
    self.detailTableView.reloadData()
  }
})
```

Comment: you define the `completion` block as being `() -> Bool` Why do you do that if you don't want to return a Bool? Also, you are never using the `completion` function in the body of `appendAllData`

Comment: I put Bool because I don't want it to return anything, just to reload the tableview after the function completes

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to check for nil before conditionally binding a variable name. The whole point of conditional binding it to check for `nil`

Comment: I cleaned up this shit-show a bit: http://pastebin.com/f3Vgsmpk

Comment: @Alexander That's a lot cleaner, thanks

Comment: @SwiftyJD May I ask why you have all these parallel arrays? It's a huge code smell

Comment: @Alexander it's for the 'numberOfRowsInSection' , each array represents a row

Comment: @SwiftyJD It's probably best to just use map/filter to produce those arrays when necessary

Comment: @Alexander I'm not entirely sure how to do something like that

Comment: You should look up a guide on `map`, `filter` and `reduce`. They're make your life ***much*** simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your completion closure signature is `completion: () -> Bool` but you used `() -> ()`. Just change function parameter from `completion: () -> Bool` to `completion: () -> Void` or `completion: () -> ()`.
And you should follow njzk2's comment.

Comment: It's nothing :)